# jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in without duplicate check

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am looking for a jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in without duplicate check. So you can select an item multiple times. 
I like Select2 plug in, but does anyone know how to disable the duplicate id check function in Select2. The creator mentioned that function in the 4.0.0 version but I could not find out how to disable that. It is mentioned [here](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/1002)

Comment: what about just asking the developer? :)

Comment: @LelioFaieta already asked. He hasn't replied.

Comment: @LelioFaieta this question about how to disable duplicate check in Select2 has been already asked in Stackoverflow but no replied yet...

Comment: if so don't duplicate the questions. You get no more options to receive an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plug in that fits perfectly to my needs.
[Tagit](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it). You can remove duplicate check with `allowDuplicates` set to true.